# How to remove/uninstall Angular7?

Tags: angular7

I am trying to unistall angular7 but it's still showing me angular 7. I want to install Angular6.

For Uninstall:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g angular-cli
sudo npm cache clean
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@6.*
```

But it still showing me Angular7.

Comment: sudo npm uninstall -g angular-cli  --purge

Comment: What command are you running that shows Angular 7?

Comment: After doing this all process then  i am checking version....ng v

Comment: Why would you want to go from 7 to 6?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

angular-cli was Angular 2, it has been @angular/cli since Angular 4.

Comment: Another Issues:-npm ERR! path /usr/bin/ng
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! Refusing to delete /usr/bin/ng: ../lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng symlink target is not controlled by npm /usr/bin
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/bin/ng
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pranavshete/.npm/_logs/2019-06-21T06_40_38_823Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can uninstall the existing version, clear cache forcefully and reinstall the version which you want.

```
sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
sudo npm cache clean --force
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@6.*
```

This will work for sure.

Thanks.

If it works then mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this command..
npm install -g @angular/cli

Also u need to update package.json file,where its version is defined
Change the "@angular/cli": "6.4.1"

After that again run the below command
npm install

Comment: I think the formatting got a bit messed up here... Shouldn't they be updating the package.json then performing the install?